# Mirroring folder on the same file server reduces the modified date by 1 hour

Tags: windows, robocopy

I am facing this weird issue in which when I mirror a folder on same file Server then in the  destination folder for all the sub folders modified date is one hour earlier to what was there in source folder for the same folder.

Say my folder1 has a sub folder folder1_sub1 whose modified date is 2/28/2011 3:54 AM.
Then in destination folder say folder2 for sub folder folder1_sub1 modified date is 2/28/2011 2:54 AM.

The same happens for files.

My best guess is that it could have happened due to Day Light Savings time, but am not sure, as the time on fileShare server(server1-fs01.services.local) and server where I run the batch file have the same time.

This is my content of the batch file which I use to mirror files

```
set args=/mir /dcopy:t /log+:"C:\log.txt" /tee

robocopy "\\server1-fs01.services.local\AppData\Folder1" "\\server1-fs01.services.local\AppData\Folder2"  %args%
```

Let me know if you any more queries.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation: use option /DST to Compensate for one-hour DST time differences. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx

PS: the newer version on robocopy doesn't run on XP or on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Used it, resulted in two hour time difference

Comment: I was using a different server where the robopy command was fired to copy the files. The server where the command was fired was 2 hour behind the server where the original files were stored. So it resulted in the time difference. Thanks for your help